# GET request with postman is working, but it does not work with python (HTTPSConnectionPool)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-requests, postman

I am trying to get JSON from an API which then can be showed on a website which is built with django and the API is made with the rest_framework. I have tried both Requests and http.client but I got the same error which is:

*HTTPSConnectionPool(host='webpageUrl' port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/donations (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(*

I have tried debugging with GET requests in Postman which works fine, however when I either use the examples provided in the documentation of the Requests library or use the code snippet generated in Postman I get the aforementioned error. Furthermore, I previously had Basic Authentication which I thought were the root of the problem, I therefore turned the authentication off but it didn't work.

This is the code I am currently trying:

```py
import requests

def available_donations(request):

    assert isinstance(request,HttpRequest)
    response = requests.get("webpageUrl/api/donations", headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'}, timeout=5)

    return render(
        request,
        'app/availableDonations.html', {'donation':response},
        {
            'title':'Overview of available donations'

            })
```

I expected to get an error about the rendering of the webpage, however from what I could read from different stackoverflow questions the error means that it couldn't find the webpage.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT 1:

I tried running the snippet code from postman on my personal computer which works. I believe that the problem is that it can't make HTTP requests to the API (which is located on the same server) with the method I used. Moreover, I tried running dummy different dummy API's with this method which works.

Comment: There is a SSL Verify setting in postman. If you turn that off does the request still work in postman?

Comment: I tried turning off the SSL certificate verification in Postman but it still works.

Comment: A few questions:
Is the python code running on the same machine you are running Postman?
Is it running natively or in a container or a VM? This really sounds like a network issue more than a Python / requests problem.

Comment: The python code is running on a Linux server hosted on a different machine, and the postman is on my personal computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that the method I was using was not valid for internal HTTPS requests. I used ifconfig to see the local ip-address, and used that instead of the host and put the ip-address in ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py. Furthermore, i disabled SSL verification with verify=False

```py
def getDonations():

    url = "https://172.19.10.5/api/donations"
    payload = ""
    headers = {
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, timeout=5, verify=False)
    print(response.text)
    return response.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Verifying the session

```
session = requests.Session()
session.verify = True

session.get("webpageUrl/api/donations", headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'}, timeout=5, verify=True)
```